# pg_restore certain tables only

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, restore

I'm looking for a way to use `pg_restore` to restore a newly-created database from a dump file, but *only certain tables* from that file. (There are a lot of extra tables in the database that are slow to restore and that I don't care about.)

I first tried `pg_restore` with the `-t`/`--table` flag, but it didn't enable the extensions I need for those tables. Not a big deal; I can manually run `psql -c "CREATE EXTENSION ..."` before the `pg_restore` command. My bigger issue is that the `-t` command seems to skip other things related to the tables, like constraints and indexes.

Indexes are annoying but I could run `pg_restore --list` and use `awk`/`grep`/etc. to get a list of indexes and pass them in to `pg_restore` with the `-I`/`--index` flag, so the process would be (I think):

1. `pg_restore -t table1 -t table2 --schema-only ...`
2. `pg_restore -I index1 -I index2 ...`
3. `pg_restore -t table1 -t table2 --data-only ...`

But **(a)** that still won't set up the constraints for me, and **(b)** it feels like I'm going down a rabbit hole with this roundabout solution for something I thought would be straightforward.

I know you can tell `pg_dump` to only dump certain tables, but I was hoping to avoid that due to the long time it takes to make dumps of my database.

Comment: How about restoring the entire schema in a 1st step (--schema-only), which will create all indexes (empty) and constraints, and the data for certain tables in a 2nd step?

Comment: Ah, of course! This worked beautifully (with `--data-only` for the second step). If you make that an official answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon. It looks like the `-t` flag prevents sequences from being restored, even when I explicitly call `pg_restore -t table_id_seq ...`. So after the restore all of my auto-incrementing IDs reset to 1. Do you know of any workarounds?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

if you're using the "custom" format , you can use the `-l` (ell) and `-L` options to do this.

1. create your dump, using the "custom" format
2. run `pg_restore -l /path/to/dump/file > table_of_contents.txt`
3. edit table_of_contents.txt and just remove references to the tables you don't want anymore. (Make sure you get all of them.  You can comment out a line with a semicolon.)
4. restore your database with `pg_restore ... -L table_of_contents.txt /path/to/dump/file`

Profit!

Comment: While kind of clunky, I suspect this works (I can no longer test to confirm that sequences work, but oh well) and I suppose one could script this to make it automatic.